# How do I remap Alt-Backspace in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I would like to assign the `Alt-Backspace` shortcut to `pop-global-mark` in Emacs (NOX). I tried doing it this way:

```
(global-set-key [M-backspace] 'pop-global-mark)
```

That didn't work. I've not been able to find the correct representation of 'backspace', it seems.

I'm on Linux (Gnome) and use the generic US Keyboard layout.

Comment: What does M-x describe-key say when you press the combination? Most likely your terminal swallows it. (Your code is correct.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(global-set-key "\M-\d" 'pop-global-mark)`.

Comment: Note that this is what Emacs recommends when you try setting `Alt-backspace` via `(global-set-key [M-DEL] 'test)`, and `DEL` is what `C-h` gives you for `backspace`.

Comment: Yup. That's where I got it from.

Answer (score 4):

`(kbd "<M-backspace>")` instead of `[M-backspace]` should work.

Comment: I think using `(kbd ...)` is always the best bet, if only from a readability standpoint.

Comment: @Tyler: No, I checked it now, it works. `[M-backspace]` works, too, though, so I guess nschum is right that the key combination get swallowed before it reaches Emacs (by the terminal, as suggested, or by the window manager, perhaps).